# Yelp/Foursquare for Denmark or how do Danes find shops?

Tags: europe, online-resources, shopping, denmark, mobile-apps

What apps do Danes use to find shops instead of Yelp/Foursquare? I'm in Odense, which is the third largest city in Denmark. I try to find mobile phone shops and secondhand bicycle shops but the results which the mentioned apps give me are few and often come with no review. I suppose some other apps are used in Denmark or Danes simply use a different kind of platform to find shops?

Comment: I am not in Denmark but I would use a search engine, like Google.

Comment: Google maps is the go-to most countries I think. Yelp is very much a "only useful in the US" thing.

Comment: @CMaster It's useful for restaurants and other tourist-y places at times in EU countries, but mostly useless otherwise indeed.

Comment: On the topic of bicycles, many years ago I was able to buy a second hand bicycle in Odense at the police auction, which used to happen weekly. It was a proud moment that I was able to navigate the auction without knowing any Danish.

Comment: [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/55.39795/10.38498) has some shops.

Comment: @CMaster And only useful if you want to see which businesses paid Yelp the most.

Comment: You are aware that people found shops before Yelp/etc appeared? There are local ads, there is walking around and using your eyes, there is asking neighbours, and dozens of other ways.

Comment: Also note that especially for older, somewhat niché shops (like bike shops specializing in used bikes), it is possible that they aren't easily found on Google; sometimes they don't even have a website. Examples of this in Odense includes the used bike shop "Cykelhjørnet" (corner of Læssøegade/Tietgens Allé). It might be useful to ask locals for recommendations instead, particularly locals who have been in the city for a few years.

Comment: I think China will block or restrict Google Maps, but that's China.  It should work fine in more Democratic countries, as long as their infrastructure's good.  (I've used it in Japan, at least.)

Comment: @Tom We're all aware of that, but my god it was awful and horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a Dane (actually living in Odense), I would use Google (including Google Maps) or ask a local of the city I was in. I would search using Danish terms such as "brugte cykler odense" in Google.

For bicycles, I don't know of any dedicated used bike stores in the city, but from my research, it does seem that a lot of the "normal bike shops" occasionally have refurbished used bikes.

Comment: Does Denmark have an online auction or small ads site? Like E-bay or the Dutch marktplaats.nl?

Comment: @Willeke Google will help you with that too.

Comment: I think the 3 relevant online classifieds sites for dealing used goods consumer to consumer in Denmark would be: Dba.dk, guloggratis.dk and Facebook marketplace.

Comment: *"danish"* → *"[Danish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Danish#Adjective)"*. *"danish"* is something else. You can [edit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/168030/edit) (change) your answer. But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written right now).

Comment: FWIW, Google Maps seems to [do just fine](https://www.google.com/maps/search/bike+shop/@56.4513555,9.2813892,12z) searching for "bike stores" and finding relevent results.

Comment: As for reviews, most use TrustPilot, e.g https://dk.trustpilot.com/review/www.designcykler.dk?utm_medium=trustbox&utm_source=Carousel

Answer (score 5):

What was previously the "yellow pages" in the telephone directory exists online at https://www.krak.dk/

- [mobile phones](https://www.krak.dk/mobiltelefoner/firmaer?ne=55.4329094711609%2C10.549364089965822&sw=55.351793082909154%2C10.287923812866211)
- [bicycles](https://www.krak.dk/cykler/firmaer?ne=55.43042580363018%2C10.534772872924806&sw=55.34930431458601%2C10.273332595825197)